# C# Add element to an Object List using variable as List key

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Let me explain, I have a model list in which I have a little more than a thousand parameters, so I have to fill the list with some variables, the thing is that I don't want to do this:

```
             list.Add(new Model{ 
                   name1= value, 
                   name2= value,
                   .....
                   name1000=value
                   });
```

I have an array that contains the names of the parameters in the list, so I was wondering if is possible to use that array of the names and in a loop get the variables fill in, something like this:

```
             list.Add(new Model{ 
                  //a loop?
                   array[0]= value 
                   });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Having a model with 1000 variables probably indicates that the code is not designed elegantly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using reflection. Code below

```
public class ModelFactory
{
    private IDictionary<string, PropertyInfo> propertiesInfo { get; set; }

    public ModelFactory()
    {
        this.propertiesInfo = typeof(Model)
                            .GetProperties()
                            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p);
    }

    public Model Create(string[] propertiesToInitialize, dynamic value)
    {
        var model = new Model();
        foreach (var propertyName in propertiesToInitialize)
        {
            if (this.propertiesInfo.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            {
                var property = this.propertiesInfo[propertyName];
                property.SetValue(model, value);
            }
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

Model to initialize

```
public class Model
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }

    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }

    public int MyProperty3 { get; set; }

    public int MyProperty4 { get; set; }

    public int MyProperty5 { get; set; }
}
```

Usage

```
public void Test()
{
    var propertiesToInitialize = new string[] { "MyProperty1", "MyProperty2", "MyProperty4" };
    var modelFactory = new ModelFactory();

    var list = new List<Model>();

    list.Add(modelFactory.Create(propertiesToInitialize, 500));

    Console.WriteLine("MyProperty1  " + list[0].MyProperty1); // 500
    Console.WriteLine("MyProperty2  " + list[0].MyProperty2); // 500
    Console.WriteLine("MyProperty3  " + list[0].MyProperty3); // 0
    Console.WriteLine("MyProperty4  " + list[0].MyProperty4); // 500
    Console.WriteLine("MyProperty5  " + list[0].MyProperty5); // 0 
}
```

However as already mentioned in comments, please reconsider your model design because model with these many properties is not optimal.

Comment: @MistyK in this example no benefit of dynamic. Initially I was thinking to take IDictionary<string,dynamic> PropertyValueToInit as parameter... so that user can init different values. It's just a sample code.